# How do I get the drag and drop to link feature working in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I'm trying to link to a .css file inside of Visual Studio Code as I'm following along with a Pluralsight course. I saw the presenter drag the .css file into the index.html file and it created the link in the head just like Visual Studio does. But for the life of me I can't get it to work. Anyone know how?

Comment: Already requested on Github [Allow to Drag and drop files from explorer into working file to produce a URL link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10895)

Comment: I'm not surprised that this feature has been requested, but the instructor I was following along with was already using it. It may have been a custom plugin that he wrote now that I think about it...

Comment: Read the contributor's comment [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19632)